# Improper Integrals as Riemann Sums and a Beautiful Limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, improper-integrals, riemann-sum

For some context, I recently encountered a beautiful limit.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}$$
To solve this we begin by taking the natural log of the inside.
$$\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)^\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)$$
Writing out the terms inside the $\ln$ makes it clear that we can express it as a sum.
$$\ln\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{1\cdot2 \dotsm n}{n\cdot n \dotsm n}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\ln\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)+\dotsm+\ln\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\ln\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)$$
So what we are looking for is the following.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\ln\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)$$
Notice that this is the Riemann Sum from $0$ to $1$ of $\ln(x)$ so we have,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\ln\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\ln(x)\ dx$$
The integral can be solved using integration by parts which I will not include here but it evaluates to $-1$.
$$\int_{0}^{1}\ln(x)\ dx=-1$$
But as we took the natural log of the expression, we must undo it by putting it to the power of $e$.
$$\therefore\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}=\frac{1}{e}$$

I was wondering if I could use the same kind of steps to make an expression equal to $e^\pi$. I realized I needed an integral based on $\ln(x)$ which evaluates to $\pi$ and found the following.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\ dx=\pi$$

However, the problem here is that this is an improper integral and the upper bound is at $\infty$. I've been looking for ways to express this as a Riemann Sum but intuitively it does not make sense to me. The point of Riemann Sums was to keep adding infinitely thin boxes infinite times, so is there any room to expand that so that the upper bound is at infinity?

Also, if you find any other integrals which can be used to make a nice expression like the one above, please include that too. I would love to solve it.

ps. This is my first post and also my first time using latex to write these equations. Any advice or suggestion is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: What do the three dots before the limit mean ?

Comment: Therefore. Now that I look at it, it may not be clear what it's referring to. That is a mistake on my end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \log \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x^2} \right) \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \log \left( 1 + \frac{n^2}{k^2} \right) \frac{1}{n} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \left[ \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 + \frac{n^2}{k^2} \right) \right] \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \left( \frac{\sinh(n\pi)}{n\pi} \right).
\end{align*}

So, the equality $\int_{0}^{\infty} \log \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x^2} \right) \, \mathrm{d}x = \pi$ is equivalent to

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac{\sinh(n\pi)}{n\pi} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} = e^{\pi}, $$

which is in fact much easier to prove only using calculus.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help. So I guess the Riemann sum of the improper integral doesn't result in an expression with n! or n^n, but instead an expression with sinh. That would also intuitively explain why the result is pi. 

Do you have any other integrals which you think might result in a nice expression?

Comment: @bob, I have some other examples of similar kinds, but unfortunately they are not particularly different from OP's one. For instance, $$\int_{0}^{1}\log(1-x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x=2\log2-2$$ translates to the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{(2n)!/2}}{n^2}=\frac{4}{e^2}.$$

Comment: I see. I think these results are still pretty cool, despite them just being variations of the original one I saw. 

I think I am going to leave this at that as I also got some help here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4624612/1141581, but I will continue to look for these nice limits in my free time. 

Thank you to everyone who helped me in the past few days. 
@Sine of the Time, Sangul Lee

Comment: And also @Claude Leibovici from the other post.

Answer (score 3):

**Not an answer**

If the problem is the bound of integration, you can make a substitution.
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx=\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx$$
In the second integral, let $1/x=t$:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{t ^2}\ln\left(1+t^2\right)dt $$
I don't know if written this way it's more managable to find the Riemann sum.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I feel like this may work. I will try it out.

Comment: @daiki You're welcome, let me know if works :)

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer**

I believe I've made some progress. First, I used the substitution by @Sine of the Time, $t=\frac{1}{x}$ to change the bounds of integration and ended up with the following.
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx=\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{t ^2}\ln\left(1+t^2\right)dt$$
Then, I looked back at the transformation from the initial problem,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\ln\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\ln(x)dx$$
and transformed both integrals similarly.
$$\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^2}\right)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{n^2}{i^2}\right)$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{t ^2}\ln\left(1+t^2\right)dt=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n
\frac{1}{\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^2}
\ln\left(1+\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^2\right)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n
\frac{n^2}{i^2}
\ln\left(1+\frac{i^2}{n^2}\right)
$$
So what we are looking for is this.
$$\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{t ^2}\ln\left(1+t^2\right)dt=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{n^2}{i^2}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^n
\frac{n^2}{i^2}
\ln\left(1+\frac{i^2}{n^2}\right)\right)$$
Combining the two summations leaves us with this.
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\ln\left(\left(1+\frac{n^2}{i^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{i^2}{n^2}\right)^\frac{n^2}{i^2}\right)$$
However, now I am stuck as I can't figure out a clever way to continue simplifying the expression. The second term $\left(1+\frac{i^2}{n^2}\right)^\frac{n^2}{i^2}$ looks somewhat similar to $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e$, but this too I can't figure out how to apply. My next step is to expand each sum individually instead of combining them like I did, and maybe some things might cancel out. Do you guys have any ideas on how to further simplify the summation?