# Clever ways to expand $\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{n^2}{i^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{i^2}{n^2}\right)^\frac{n^2}{i^2}$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, products, riemann-sum

**This is a continuation from [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4622218/1141581).**

From my work in the link above I found the following.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\ln\left(\left(1+\frac{n^2}{i^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{i^2}{n^2}\right)^\frac{n^2}{i^2}\right)=\pi$$
I was looking for clever ways to somehow expand this so it can be expressed with factorials $!$ and powers $n^n$ just like this.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\ln\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\ln\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)+\dotsm+\ln\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{1\cdot2 \dotsm n}{n\cdot n \dotsm n}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)$$
However, the problem is I can't figure out a way to expand this inside the $\ln$.
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{n^2}{i^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{i^2}{n^2}\right)^\frac{n^2}{i^2}$$
Maybe there's no way? I've tried expanding each product individually but that too I haven't had any success. Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P_n=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{n^2}{i^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{i^2}{n^2}\right)^\frac{n^2}{i^2}$$ resisted  the different CAS I tried.

Taking the logarithm and looking at the continuous case
$$Q_n=\int_1^{n}\left( \log   \left(1+\frac{n^2}{i^2}\right)+\frac{n^2 }{i^2}\log \left(1+\frac{i^2}{n^2}\right)\right)\,di$$
$$Q_n=n \left(n \log \left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}(n)-\pi \right)-\log \left(1+n^2\right)$$ which, asymptotically, is
$$Q_n=\pi\,n-2\log(n)-3+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \,\frac {(-1)^n}{k (k+1) (2 k+1)\,n^{2k}}$$

Reworking $\log(P_n)$ in this spirit
$$\log(P_n)=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\log (\pi )\right)+\pi\,n+\log(n)+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$