# Compute $\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^n (\frac{k}{n})^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Compute $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^n (\frac{k}{n})^{1/n}$$
I tried to compute term by term, and the limit of each term for $k$ gives me 1. Thus, I assume the product of 1 is 1. However, Wolfram Alpha gives an answer of $1/e$. How do I compute this limit?

PS: I tried to make use of the Stirling's formula for $n!$, but I can't make it work.

Comment: Compute the limit of the logarithme...

Comment: Note that the product is exactly $\sqrt[n]{n! }/n$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4622218/1141581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "PS: I tried to make use of the Stirling's formula for !
> , but I can't make it work"

However, Stirling's approximation would work:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{1/n} = \\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left((n!)^{1/n} \cdot \dfrac{1}{n}\right) 
\quad\xrightarrow{\Large{n! \space \approx \space} \normalsize{\dfrac{\sqrt{2\pi n}\cdot n^n}{e^n}}} 
\\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\sqrt{2^{1/n}}\cdot\sqrt{\pi^{1/n}}\cdot n^{1/2n}\cdot n \cdot \dfrac{1}{n}\right) \cdot e^{-1}
= 1 \cdot e^{-1}$$

Comment: Sorry, why is the first equality true?

Comment: @OriginK. Look at the numerator and denominator separately
$$\prod_{k=1}^n k=n!\quad \prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n^n}$$
now just take the power of $1/n$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\ln(L)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\ln(\frac{k}{n})=\int^1_0\ln(x) dx =-1$$

$$\implies L=e^{-1}$$

Comment: Oh, I just realized my mistake. I took the logarithm for each term instead of the entire thing

Answer (score 1):

$$P_n=\prod_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
Take logarithms and expand it
$$\log(P_n)=-\frac 1n \log(n)+\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^n\log(k) =-\frac 1n \log(n)+\frac{\log(n!)} n $$ Using Stirling approximation
$$\log(P_n)=-1+\frac{\log (2 \pi n)}{2
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Now, Taylor series using
$$P_n=e^{\log(P_n)}=\frac 1e \left(1+\frac{\log (2 \pi n)}{2
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)  \right)$$ which is in a relative error smaller than $1.0$% if $n>16$ and smaller than $0.10$% if $n>67$